# Alterar o DPI de uma imagem C#

Tags: imagem, wpf, dpi

Pessoal estou desenvolvendo uma app em WPF e em um determinado ponto estou precisando converter o DPI de uma imagem, como faço?

Estou utilizando a classe `System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage`

E para carregar a imagem uso o seguinte código:

```
var fileUri = new Uri(openDlg.FileName);
var bitmap = new BitmapImage();
bitmap.BeginInit();
bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.None;
bitmap.UriSource = fileUri;
bitmap.EndInit();
```

Uma opção seria fazer o calculo do resize dessa maneira:

```
double resizeFactor = 96 / currentDpi;
int width = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.PixelWidth * resizeFactor);
int height = Convert.ToInt32(bitmap.PixelHeight * resizeFactor);
```

Isso até funciona mas não está dando bom =/

Se conhecerem uma biblioteca tbm ajuda :D

Comment: Qual o problema no final das contas? Você não sabe como usar `width` e `height` para alterar o DPI?

Comment: No final das contas eu tenho imagens em 3 resoluções (DPI), 72, 96 e 120... Preciso transformar todas em 96, independente se aumentara o width e height

Comment: galera deu certo, usei o framework Emgu CV, como eu já iria usa-lo para fazer equalização do histograma acabei usando o resize dele mesmo